# how to import file in angular js and in which sequence need to import?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I make a controller in demo .I try to test using karma, jasmine to test my controller.But I have issue of importing the file .
I want to know how to import the file and what is the sequence of importing file

when I write like that in **karma.conf.js file** it show module not found .not able to test my controller.

```
'app/**/*.js',
            'app/*.js',
            'app/home/controller/*.js',
            'app/**/*.html',
           'test/**.js'
```

**whole code**

```
 files: [

        'bower_components/angular/angular.js' ,
        'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js' ,
        'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js' ,
        'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js' ,
        'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js' ,




        'app/**/*.js',
        'app/*.js',
        'app/home/controller/*.js',
        'app/**/*.html',
       'test/**.js'
    ],
```

but when I write like that it work perfectly why ?

```
 files: [

        'bower_components/angular/angular.js' ,
        'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js' ,
        'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js' ,
        'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js' ,
        'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js' ,




        'app/home/*.js',
        'app/app.js',
        'app/home/controller/*.js',
        'app/**/*.html',
       'test/**.js'
    ],
```

I want to know how to best way to import the file ..and in which sequence i need to import the file ?

```
'app/home/*.js',
 'app/home/controller/*.js',
            'app/app.js',
```

because when I import controller file above .still show an error why ?

It Question is related to this Question

[How to remove module not found error in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378305/how-to-remove-module-not-found-error-in-angular/34378817?noredirect=1#comment56500817_34378817)

any update..?

Comment: The order matters: you can't add a component to a module if you haven't defined the module before. So the file defining the module must be loaded before the file trying to add a component to that module.

Comment: ok ..got it ..why ** not work

Comment: why 'app/**/*.js', not work

Comment: Because app/**/*.js loads all the JS files under app, recursively, and the order it uses causes the module to be used before being defined.

Comment: so if I have 50 files in my project ..so i need to add in karma.conf.js file byt name only mean i need include by name not by star (*)

Comment: what is best way to include file ?

Comment: Define your modules in a specific, unique file. Load that file first. Then load all the other ones.